`new` keyword & 'GetComponent<>'
I'm curious why in Unity, instead of using the new keyword typically used in C# for inter-class access, we use private Movement2D movement2D; and movement2D = GetComponent<Movement2D>(); instead.
I'm currently facing an issue in Unity, and I'm not sure how to resolve it. Any suggestions?

Impossible to suggest a solution if you don't explain what the issue you're facing is. But as for the new keyword, the component already exists on the object, if you were to create a new one it will not be the same instance that is attached to the GameObject. The closer parallel to new Component is AddComponent, which constructs the component but also does other Unity things about it, which they wouldn't be able to do if they had you create the new instance yourself.

Frameworks which hide the typical way of constructing objects are common enough that there's a word for the "rare" times when you do have a standard object like from the textbooks - POCO (plain old C# object)

well GetComponent, goes and gets an existing component.. new, makes a new class instance. If you want to add a component you can do so with AddComponent :P but if you dont explain what the issue is its hard to help

You can still use the "new" keyword as you do with any C# application. But "GetComponent<>()" is part of the Unity Engine and is used to actually get access to a specific component that is attached to a GameObject. In your example, if you call "GetComponent();" as it is, it will try and search for "Movement2D" component on the game object that your MonoBehaviour script is attached to.

@PavlosMavris you can use new on a Component type but you never should! It will cause all sorts of misbehavior - for instance most of the built-in properties failing as there is no underlying GameObject nor the c++ layer component instance that new c# instance will be attached to. Till today I still don't understand why Unity in that case only throws a warning most people just ignore instead of a hard exception though ^^

@derHugo yes exactly. Never use the 'new' keyword for MonoBehaviour class.

You need to understand that the c# layer that your scripts live in isn't the actual game engine. Everything in your scene is actually a c++ object, with a friendly c# wrapper to help you talk to it.
If you just create a new component in your c# land, you're only creating this wrapper - there is no actual 'real' c++ component under it. This is why calling creating components in this way is not allowed.
When you add a component to a gameobject, either in the scene or with AddComponent, you create a real c++ component attached to the c++ gameobject. Then to get a reference to this object, you use the function GetComponent which gives you an interface to the real component.
This is why you can’t just use new, creating a new c# interface without an underlying c++ object is meaningless. If you need a new component then consider adding it in the scene with the "Add Component" button so it is serialised into your object, or you can add one at runtime as mentioned earlier with AddComponenet.

when you are working with a GameObject, components (ex. Movement2D that you mentioned) are already created C# objects. it means behind curtain Unity already newed them so you need to call GetComponent to get already newed object.
there is another function AddComponent that you can call in order to add a new component to a GameObject.
in Unity you don't new components or MonoBehaviours
